# Show that $\left|X\right|=\left|Y\right|$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Let $A, B$, two sets. $X$ is the set of all relations from $A$ to $B$, and $Y$ is the set of all functions from $A$ to $P(B)$ (power-set of $B$).

Prove that $\left|X\right|=\left|Y\right|$.

**My Solution:**
$\left|A \right| = a$,
$\left|B \right| = b$

$\left|Y\right| = \left| A\rightarrow P(B) \right| = \left| P(B) \right|^{\left|A \right|} = (2^b)^a = 2^{ab}$

$\left|X \right| = \left|P(A\times B \right)|$

$(*)$ Now, since every $\left<a,b\right>$ can be in the relation or not. We have $2^{ab}$ relations.

I've been told I didn't treat the infinite case (Maybe the meaning is I cannot use $(*)$ for the infinite case).

What should I do instead (or in addition to the finite case)?

**Update:**
I was guided not use functions. Instead, I should show it using cardinals arithmetics.

Comment: It is a bit confusing, if $X$ is the set of all relations, then $|X|$ is probably $2^{ab}$, not $ab$...

Comment: Sorry, that's sort of a typo.

Comment: Yes, you should change your notation a bit. Also, to show that two sets have the same cardinality, you can establish a bijection between them (and this is usually the best method, because it covers the infinite case too). Show that there is a bijection from $X$ to $Y$. So corresponding to every relation from $A$ to $B$, there is a unique function from $A$ to $\mathcal{P}(B)$, and vice-versa.

Comment: I think now the idea applies to the infinite case as well. Even for infinite cardinals, you still have $2^{ab}$ is the cardinality of all subsets, you have that $ab=ba$ and $(2^b)^a=2^{ab}$ so there should not be a problem.. (just maybe change the $(2^a)^b$ to $(2^b)^a$, it will be less confusing..)

Comment: @M.Vinay, I updated the question, I have to prove it directly using cardinals arithmetics.

Comment: @AnnieOK Okay, but I still find your notation $|A\times B|$ confusing. Do you mean $|\mathcal{P}(A\times B)|$? Because $|A \times B|$ is still $ab$ (even if you don't write it), but $|X| = 2^{ab}$.

Comment: @PeterFranek, for my understanding the **combinatorical explanation** cannot work for the infinite case. Maybe it can be explained in another way.

Comment: Corrected the errors, @M.Vinay

Comment: @AnnieOK: If you show that the cardinalities of two sets equal $2^{ab}$ then they are equal. I don't see now what's wrong with your answer, or what else should be explained.. Even in infinite case, the cardinality of $\mathcal{P}(X)$ is $2^{|X|}$ etc..

Comment: Can you explain why $\left|P(A\times B \right)| = 2^{ab}$ for every $a,b$? The combinatorical explanation is failing for the infinite case.

Comment: @AnnieOK Agree with Peter. It's correct now. You can directly write $|X| = |\mathcal{P}(A \times B)| = 2^{|A\times B|} = 2^{|A||B|} = 2^{ab}$ in the same step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should define a function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ and show that this function is a bijection. Think about how you could describe a relation between $A$ and $B$ by a function from $A$ to $\mathcal{P}(B)$.

Hint: for $x\in X$ and $a\in A$ you could set $f(x)(a) = \{b\in B\,\,|\,\,(a,b)\in x \}$.

---

Update: You seem to have solved the update already yourself. Anyway:
$$
|Y| = |\mathcal{P}(B)|^{|A|} = 2^{|B|^{|A|}} = 2^{|A||B|} = |X|,
$$
where the last equality follows, since we can choose to include/exclude each $(a,b)$ which gives two options per element.

Comment: Thank you @Marc. Can you refer to my update?